# Android screen-sharing from one mobile to other over long distance

Tags: android, screensharing

I want to implement a screen sharing app. One mobile is the server and the other one is the client. The server is sharing its screen content with clients.
constraints are:
Both devices are at a far distance so that means the use of internet is required.

I can do it with:
a. Bluetooth
b. Wi-Fi (near by up to certain range limit)

but I want to implement it for a very long distance.
lets say(2000 km)
I have searched a lot everywhere but couldn't find anything.
Any source code and any example would be helpful to me.
I know a bit about team viewer sdk for the same but I am unable to implement it.

Comment: Please read this **[ask]**

Comment: i guess question is understandable for one who really knows about it.

Comment: I think you should have a server database, why you don't try Firebase?

Comment: thanks gianhtran for your reply.. it looks helpful, i wasn't aware about this ,that i can use this firebase too as server, just read about this from https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible